# PyCharm: Introspection of library (specifically smartsheet API) does not work without `assert`

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, smartsheet-api

I am using PyCharm Professional and I am having difficulty utilizing the autocomplete/introspection of the smartsheet library.

The JetBrains documentation suggests that I ensure that the library is installed within the interpreter and the interpreter is configured for this project.  I have done both, but still the introspection is not working:

[image: the picture below is from the 'External Libraries' folder in the project tree]

When I try to use the auto complete, none of the class attributes appear:

[image]

But when I add the `assert isinstance(test_col, smartsheet.smartsheet.models.column.Column)` I start to see useful autocomplete results:

[image]

Is this just a byproduct of the structure of the smartsheet API for Python or is there another setting in PyCharm I can set to enable the autocomplete?

Here's the code (minus the individual sheet id):

```py
import smartsheet
import config

smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(config.api_token)
smartsheet_client.errors_as_exceptions(True)

response = smartsheet_client.Sheets.list_sheets(include="attachments,source", include_all=True)

sheet_id = 'MY_SHEET_ID_64'
edit_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)
type(edit_sheet.columns[0])

test_col = edit_sheet.columns[0]
assert isinstance(test_col, smartsheet.smartsheet.models.column.Column)
test_col.id
```

Comment: I'm not PyCharm or Python user (at all). But knowing how other JetBrains' IDEs are working, it must be that the Smartsheet does not provide any comments with types for parameters or return values. Have a look here and try adding such typehint comment in your own code: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. This provides a cleaner method to access the introspection as opposed to the `assert` command. I am still confused, however, why the absence of comments in the smartsheet library would limit the autocomplete/introspection but the typehint comment would enable it.

Comment: AFAIK Python did not have "natural" typehints (a language way to specify what type this variable/parameter is etc) till a recent time (introduced in Python 3.5). Before that you  could only provide it by using special comments for your IDE to use. So if `smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet()` method does not declare what it returns (could be to make it compatible with older Python versions) and does not have such comments (once again, I'm not Python user/need to check the source code), then how the IDE should know about it? Anyway: check https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: I truly appreciate that you would take the time to share your insights! Thank you so much.